# Can I somehow get my program to convert characters to integers?

Tags: integer, char, stack, postfix-notation

I have been running this and typing `"12+"` as the expression. 'm down to trying to add the top value and next value and it keeps giving me the result `'c'` but I want the result to be 3. So is there any way to get my program to convert char 'c' to int '3' and char 'd' to int 4 and so on ?

```c++
//array based stack implementation
class Stack
{
private:
    int capacity;        //max size of stack
    int top;            //index for top element
    char *listArray;       //array holding stack elements

public:
    Stack (int size = 50){ //constructor
        capacity = size;
        top = 0;
        listArray = new char[size];
    }

    ~Stack() { delete [] listArray; } //destructor


    void push(char it) {    //Put "it" on stack
        listArray[top++] = it;
    }
    char pop() {   //pop top element
        return listArray [--top];
    }

    char& topValue() const { //return top element
        return listArray[top-1];
    }

    char& nextValue() const {//return second to top element
        return listArray[top-2];
    }


    int length() const { return top; } //return length



};

int main()
{
    string exp;
    char it = ' ';
    int count;
    int push_length;


    cout << "Enter an expression in postfix notation:\n";
    cin >> exp;
    cout << "The number of characters in your expression is " << exp.length() << ".\n";
    Stack STK;

    for(count= 0; count < exp.length() ;count++)
    {

        if (exp[count] == '+')
        {
          it = exp[count - 1];
          cout << it << "?\n";

              while (!isdigit(it))
        {
            cout << it << "!\n";
            it = exp[count--];
        }

        STK.push(it);
        cout << STK.topValue() << "\n";


        it = exp[count - 2];
        cout << it << "\n";

        if (isdigit(it))
        {
            STK.push(it);

        }
        cout << STK.topValue() << "\n";
        cout << STK.nextValue() << "\n";
        it = STK.topValue() + STK.nextValue();
        cout << it << "\n";

        STK.pop();
        STK.pop();
        STK.push(it);
        cout << STK.topValue() << "\n";

        }


    }
    cout << "The number of characters pushed into the stack is " << STK.length() << ".\n";
    push_length = STK.length();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: long time since I've done c / c++

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use something like STK.push(it-'0') instead of STK.push(it).

Comment: what would that do exactly?

Comment: @Richard, Sorry there was a mistake in typing. I edited the post. your it variable contains the characters from input. You can subtract ascii value of zero from digit chars to convert each char to digit. So you can push the digit instead of pushing the characters ascii codes.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
int a = (int)'a';
int c = (int)'c';
int ans = (c-a) + 1 ; // ans will be 3
```

Comment: How can I get it to convert all characters to digits ?